# Chef - finding the missing attribute NilClass

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

**Context** - We have a massive amount of Chef attributes to perform our install, something like 3000+ have now been defined and change per environment.

**Problem** - Sometimes a Chef recipe will reference a non-existent attribute `node[:mystuff][:typo]`. This results in the following error:

```
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/<yyy>/recipes/something.rb
undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
```

This is a worthless error because it doesn't let me know exactly what node/attribute is missing. Even running with `chef-client -l debug` doesn't help. `knife cookbook test <x>` doesn't help because syntactically it is correct. Is there a way to get it to print out the exact line number that is causing the error? The recipe may contain 10s or 100s of attributes so it is a huge time waster going through line by line to discover a typo.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote [Chef Sugar](https://github.com/sethvargo/chef-sugar)'s [deep_fetch](https://github.com/sethvargo/chef-sugar#node) method precisely for this reason.

The error you are getting is just the by-product of Ruby hashes. For more information on `deep_fetch`, you can also see my blog post on the subject: https://sethvargo.com/delicious-new-chef-sugars/

Comment: Chef Sugar looks awesome!

Comment: Yes, Chef Sugar should be incorporated into core Chef IMO. :)

Comment: Thank you for the response. In the short term I might not be able to get Chef Sugar approved for my project but will look to it for the future.